# jackson JsonInclude Non_Null not ignoring working on nested Object Properties

Tags: json, spring, jackson

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Flight implements Serializable {

    private TrackInformation trackInformation;

    private MiscData miscData;

    private CargoItems cargoItems;

}



Controller class

  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/getFlightByKey", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Flight getFlightByKey(@RequestBody @Valid final FlightInfoRequestDTO request)throws NoDataFoundException  {
    return flightInfoAppService.getFlightByKey(request.getKey());
}
```

public class TrackInformation extends AbstractRecord {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5226745652646434627L;

private String sourceFacility;

private ComputerID computerID;

private String sourceTimeStamp;

private Double latitude;

private Double longitude;

private ReportedAltitude reportedAltitude;

private Integer speed;
```

}

public abstract class AbstractRecord implements Serializable {

}

Now the returned flight object has null fields for nested objects. How can I ignore null fields from nested objects.

did hashCode and equals override in TrackInformation.

Comment: can you show the nested classes `TrackInformation` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` on every nested class as well to ignore nested class null value properties

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TrackInformation extends AbstractRecord {

 // properties

}
```